# Customise Quick Launch Depending on Site Page

Tags: sharepoint-server, quick-launch

We have a Site Collection with many Lists and Libraries, all showing in the Quick Launch. We've sorted the Quick Launch accordingly, but I'd like to be able to have the Quick Lauch only show certain links depending on which List or Library someone is viewing, rather than showing them all, all of the time.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to achieve it?

We're running 2013 Foundation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using SharePoint OOTB features, it is not possible to make dynamic quick launch navigation structure depending on the current page user is viewing.

However, If you want to make some quick launch links available to set/group of people and hide that link for another set/group of people then you can achieve this using **Target Audience** in SharePoint.

Check below references on how to set the target audience on quick launch navigation links.

**References**:

1. [Target content to specific audiences](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)
2. [Target Audience on Navigation Links](https://www.google.com/amp/s/tracyvanderschyff.com/2016/09/17/target-audience-on-navigation-links-in-sharepoint/amp/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Target Audience isn't available on SP 2013 Foundation. It's also not what I'm after. Maybe someone knows a script to add to a page that could be tweaked for each scenario.